# chrome extension to react to incoming web messenger changes?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Is there a listener that fires whenever a tab notifies the user of an event?
F.e. whenever a message in Whatsapp-Web or any other webapp messenger arrives?

chrome.tabs does not seem to have one as `onUpdated` does not fire.